# How to get the exact value shown inside a cell using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm try to using **Apache POI** to get cells value of an EXCEL file, in order to show those values inside another application.

I have a problem, since I don't get the exact value I see on Excel.
For example:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|What is inside the Excel |  What I get with Apache POI   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|     2019-03-02          |  Sat Mar 02 20:45:00 CET 2019 | getDateCellValue()
-----------------------------------------------------------
|     19                  |    19.0                       | getNumericCellValue()
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

What should I do to get the exact value I see inside the cell when I open the file with Excel?

Thank you

Comment: You already got the exact value...

Comment: Do using `DataFormatter ` as shown in https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents. Do ignoring the code after `// Alternatively, get the value and format it yourself`.

Comment: You got exact values, it's up to you how you format and output those.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. in my Excel I have a value of "5.347838", however poi returns "5.347837999999999" ... in another row I have "768.13" but poi gives me "768.1300000000001" .. so it looks that behind the scenes a conversion to double happens